# Unable to Decode Japenese Decoded Value

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, web, decode

I have got below values from response from nicos japense payment gateway and unable to decode to actual value sincec 1 month. Please please help me in this to get decoded.

Value: %ufffd%ufffd%ufffd%u0742%ufffd%ufffd%ufffd%ufffdx%ufffdX

Comment: You can't, because `%ufffd` is the value of the [Unicode Replacement Character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm), used when you try to read ASCII text using the wrong codepage. You may be using the wrong encoding in the request, or the text may be in an invalid encoding to begin with. How did you make the *request*? What type, encoding did you request? Why not use UTF8? Where does the text come from? Could it be that the invalid text/codepage was sent from *your* side?

Comment: BTW this is [URL encoding/percent encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46293730/unable-to-decode-japenese-decoded-value). It's used in URLs and form POST bodies. It should *NOT* be stored as is, or returned as content. Maybe someone POSTed the data without actually using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type?

Comment: What happened 1 month ago? Did your company deploy a new service? Form? Does it work correctly? Does the *data* appear correcly in the gateway's reports, administrative site? If not, it's that new service that mangled the data. If the data appears as %ufffd, it means that the new service treats Unicode incorrectly.

Comment: The good news is, the problem is clear. The code is  trying to convert ASCII (8-bit) data to Unicode using the wrong codepage. Just make sure Unicode/UTF8 is used everywhere. .NET for example uses Unicode for strings, so it works "by default" unless someone breaks it by hard-coding a codepage on the page or configuration. The bad news is that if the data was sent to NICOS this way, it was destroyed on your side before it even reached the gateway

Comment: I have tried all the possibilities for UTF8 still it is not working. Can somebody provide sample code to convert this value please.

Comment: Tried *what*? You haven't posted *any* code. *That* string won't produce any Japanese characters anyway - %ufffd is an **error** character. The text is gone

Comment: BTW *that* encoding is [non-standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Non-standard_implementations) - in fact it was *rejected* by W3C. Perhaps someone used `escape()` in Javascript to encode the data incorrectly before posting? In that case the text was destroyed before it was even posted

Comment: You can try to convert the URL encoded string to HTML encoding by replacing `%u....` with `&#x....;` using the regex `%u(\w{4})`, and `regex.Replace(input,"&#x$1;")`. After that, you can use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(replaced)` to decode the string. Unfortunately, this will only return a series of Unicode replacement characters �. You need to find what mangled the text in the first place

Comment: Please see my tries. You can update the code if any ideas or i am missing something. https://dotnetfiddle.net/3sB9Xb#

Comment: You still don't understand. No matter what you try you won't get anything out of this string. It doesn't contain Japanese or any other characters. It contains **ERROR CHARACTERS**. Trying to make it Unicode won't help. IT IS ALREADY UNICODE. .NET STRINGS ARE UNICODE

Comment: On the other hand those 1252, 932 codepages are a great way to destroy the text. *Unicode* strings don't need codepages. By trying to convert between 1252 and 932 you guarantee that the text will be destroyed.

Comment: Your code mentions a database. What database? What is the field's type? Are you sure the problem isn't caused by the way you *read* the text from the database? The big databases have a Unicode type (NCHAR/NVARCHAR) so you have to really try to store Unicode in the wrong way. MySQL though treats Unicode as just another encoding over CHAR. This leads to frequent problems if the field's codepage *isn't* UTF8 or the connection's language isn't UTF8 when reading or writing

Comment: Unfortunately, if the codepage was wrong while reading from the database you'd get � for any misshaped characters. If the text in the database is  `%ufffd`, it means the data was already lost before it was written to the database. Someone,somewhere performed an invalid URL encoding and converted the Japanese text to an invalid series of `%`, `u`, `f`, `f`, `f`, `d`,`%`

Comment: It is not fetched from the Database it is a value received from niccos as response for the field BankBranchName. in request.form i get this value